# Unable to load asset after I deleted and restored the asset folder

Tags: flutter, loading, assets

I am a beginner in Flutter. The problem I faced was that the asset was not loading. In this case, it was loading at the beginning of the application, but I had mistakenly deleted that folder and again restored it. After that, it shows that the asset is unable to load. I have searched in stack overflow, checked spaces in pubspec, and also ran Flutter Clean and restarted VS Code.[error ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpHMO.png)[pubspec file ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO2mr.png)[code in file ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ccTh.png)

Answer (score 0):

the path `json/items.json` is seems like wrong.

as i see from your pubspec yaml screenshot , your folder's name should be `new_asset`.

so the correct path is gonna be like this : `new_asset/items.json`